# Ajax.ActionLink post entire model from a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a view that is strongly typed to a ViewModel.  Is it possible to pass all of the data from a model in the view, back to a controller action?  Something like this?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("(Export to Excel)", "ExportCsv", "SurveyResponse", new {  
ResultsViewModel = Model }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

And then collect the data from ResultsViewModel as a parameter in another controller

```
public ActionResult ExportCsv(ResultsViewModel resultsviewmodel)
{

}
```

Comment: no you can not pass ViewModel as parameter in @Ajax.ActionLink if you want these in POST then you must be submit the form using Html.BeginForm or Ajax.BeginForm. OR still if want to pass values using Ajax.Action link then pass each single value of ViewModel.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot pass entire view model like this in an action link. You could pass only the `id` of this model and then retrieve the actual model using this `id` from wherever you retrieved it initially:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "(Export to Excel)", 
    "ExportCsv", 
    "SurveyResponse", 
    new { id = Model.Id }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }
)
```

As an alternative you could serialize the model as a javascript literal and then send it as a JSON data with the AJAX request:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "(Export to Excel)", 
    "ExportCsv", 
    "SurveyResponse", 
    null, 
    new { @class = "exportCsv" }
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.exportCsv').click(function() {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to make below works,

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("(Export to Excel)", "ExportCsv", "SurveyResponse", 
new { Model.F1, Model.F2, Model.OtherFields }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportCsv(ResultsViewModel resultsviewmodel)
{

}
```

This is a http post, but the data in not in "form data", it's encoded in request's URL (but not a http get).

Looks like MVC automatically converts the individual fields into a single model.

URL has a length limits, large model may fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your model's Id to the controller and get json result:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("(Export to Excel)", "ExportCsv", "SurveyResponse", new {  
id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

And in controller you will have:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExportCsv(int id)
{
//Here get the whole model from your repository for example:
var model=GetModelByModelId(id);
//And do everything you want with your model.
return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `[HttpGet]` in controller and then `HttpMethod = "POST" ` in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. It kind of defeats the point of `HTTP POST` in my oppionion. But hey it gets the job done.

My Ajax:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "RemoveSubjectFromCategory","Categories", new { SubjectId = item.Id, CategoryId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "GET"})
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveSubjectFromCategory(RemoveSubjectFromCategoryModel model)
{}
```

My Binding Model:

```
public class RemoveSubjectFromCategoryModel
{
    [Required]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```